# regex to parse certain html tags

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a string with parts of it enclosed in html tags, mostly **span** and **strong**. I would like to split it in parts and get the text, tag name, and class attributes for each part

```
Take <span class="victoria line-text">Victoria line</span> to <strong>Highbury & Islington</strong>
```

So for the above text there are 4 parts that I want to extract.

```
        var result = new MyObj[]
        {
            new MyObj{ Text="Take "},
            new MyObj{ Text="Victoria line", Tag="span", ClassAttribute="victoria line-text" },
            new MyObj{ Text=" to "},
            new MyObj{ Text="Highbury & Islington", Tag="strong"},
        };
```

**It's not a valid XML/HTML** (just a text with some parts of it enclosed in tags) so I decided to use some simple regex to parse the values I need. 
I managed to get the span info using this code

```
        var str = "Take <span class=\"victoria line-text\">Victoria line</span> to <strong>Highbury & Islington</strong>";
        Regex regex = new Regex("<span class=\"(.*?)\">(.*?)</span>");
        if(regex.IsMatch(str))
        {
            MatchCollection collection = regex.Matches(str);
            foreach(Match m in collection)
            {
                string text = m.Groups[2].Value;  //Victoria line
                string classes = m.Groups[1].Value; //victoria line-text
                Console.WriteLine(text + "   " + classes);
            }
        }
```

Is it possible through regex to get the info for all parts?

The input will contain plain text with possible invalid unescaped html characters (i.e. &, ' " ) , just some part of it wrapped in span or strong tags. XmlDocument or other libraries throw exception because It's not a proper html.

Comment: if it's an html input why don't use a html parser?

Comment: I stated It's not enclosed in <> and the text can contain &

Comment: Please read this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/33

Answer (score 0):

Parsing html by using Regex is always tricky so I would not recommend Regex here. What I would rather recommend is usign existing libraries which has this done pretty well. Have a look at [AngleSharp](https://anglesharp.github.io/) or [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) - both are available as nugets.

Note: don't worry about it not being wrapped in <> - you can do it by your own, just try to parse `<p>{yourString}</p>`